# C++ pass an array to a function without knowing its type

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

I want to make a function that takes an array as an argument with ANY type and returns its length like the following example:

```cpp
unsigned int getLength(array)
{
   return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to even possible to pass an array without knowing its type, I hope I explained my question well, thank you...

Comment: Have you considered templates?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt can you give an example

Comment: Just use `std::array`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use templates as shown below. In particular, we can make use of **template nontype parameter** `N` to represent the length of the passed array and **template type parameter** `T` to represent the type of the element inside the array.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
//--------------------------v--------------->type of elements inside array named arr
std::size_t getLength(const T (&arr)[N])
//-----------------------------------^------>length of the array
{
    return N ;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    std::cout<<getLength(arr)<<std::endl;
    
    std::string arr2[] = {"a", "b"};
    std::cout<<getLength(arr2)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/TNnGYRP1vx)

---

Note with C++17 there is also an option to use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Comment: Thanks it is pretty well explained and solves the problem